Subsequence Process of Non-Markovian Stochastic Process
I have a problem that I haven't encountered before and would like to know if there is  literature on the problem.
Assume $X_t$ is a non-Markovian stochastic dynamical system and that $X_t \in S=\{1,2,3,4,5,...m\}$. I am developing an optimal stopping policy at the subsequence level. That is, for a given state subsequence $\{s_{\tau}\}$, I define the following increasing sequence of optional stopping times $\{\tau_i\} = \inf \{t : t>\tau_{i-1} \wedge X_{t} = s_i \}$.
For example, given a state subsequence of $\{s_{\tau}\}=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and a sequence of states generated by my process $\{X_t\}=\{\textbf{1},4,5,4,5,\textbf{2},8,7,5,\textbf{3}\}$, the process generated these optional stopping times $\{\tau_i\}=\{1, 6, 10\}$ and we have that $\{X_1=1,X_6=2,X_{10}=3\}$ was the trajectory observed by the subsequence process.
Moreover, I also have a stopping time at $T$ where the entire subsequence process is stopped. That is, continuing the example, if $T=8$, then my subsequence process would only be $\{X_1=1,X_6=2\}$.
Have you ever seen something like this before, and if so, where can I read more about it? If you think I'm overcomplicating things, please let me know.
